# Does Resident Evil 7 require a VR headset?

Tags: resident-evil-7

I bought Resident Evil 7 recently on PS4 for a family member, but on the home screen under the title it says "PS VR". In the store it says that it's VR compatible but is a VR set necessary to play the game? I've tried looking it up but I can't find anything that says yes or no.

Comment: The answer is not mandatory, but the small VR Logo makes reference, this game is VR compatible, I have it and its a really amazing experience. If the game itself is very scary, on the VR its amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PC you certainly don't need the VR headset (speaking mostly from experience, but you can find many streamers/speedrunners that run the game without a VR headset).  I went over to twitch and did find some streams that were on PS4 and the streamer did not have a headset on (for instance, [here](https://www.twitch.tv/geeketiquette/video/266261843)).  Furthermore, the PS4 store itself does not sell a VR version of the game, just the game itself as VR compatible (seen [here](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/grid/search-game/1?gameContentType=games&query=resident%20evil%207)).

Comment: He's playing today perfectly fine without the Headset. Thanks for the help!